# Splitting multiline into several same-length multilines

Tags: postgis, spatialite

Is there a method to convert a multiline geometry into several multiline geometries having the same length?

For example break this:

```
MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 3 1, 3 1.5, 2.5 1.5))
```

Into [approximately] same-length segments with the length of 1:

```
MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 2 1))
MULTILINESTRING((2 1, 3 1))
MULTILINESTRING((3 1, 3 1.5, 2.5 1.5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with either PostGIS or SpatiaLite (per your tags) using the [ST_Segmentize()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) function.

In spatialite, its going to look something like:

```
SELECT AsText(ST_Segmentize(GeomFromText("MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 3 1, 3 1.5, 2.5 1.5))"), 1.0));
```

The length is in the same spatial units as the geometry.

If you get an error about "No such function" or similar, its likely your spatialite is a bit old, or was build without lwgeom support.

In PostGIS, it'll be similar, but you may need to be explicit about how you specify the geometry (or geography) - see the documentation for examples and special conditions.

Comment: But perhaps the meaning was to continue further than to densify and copy 1 unit long fragments each into a new linestring.

Comment: user30184 is right, ST_Segmentize simply ensures that there are no segments shorter than specified length. AFAIK it will not extract multiline fragments of desired length, which is what I actually need (see third line in the expected result).

Comment: OK, if you really need multiple results, plain SQL isn't going to do it. Can you update the question with what other tools you can use?

Comment: With linear referencing it is probably doable somehow. Probably not with polylines but with simple lines somehow like: take the length of the whole linestring, use Spatialite function Line_Interpolate_Point and place a point to first splitting position, split the linestring between start point - split 1. Place second interpolated point, split between split 1 - split 2 etc.

Comment: ST_Split will do it for polylines, but you need a loop to get multiple results. Hence the question about tools.